# HDMI output flickering in Hummingbird allwinner A20

Tags: audio, video, hdmi

I'm using Hummingbird allwinner a20 development board, I'm playing 1080p video on this board and working fine with 7" LCD but when I connect HDMI cable to it video and audio not playing well in LED TV also there is so much flickering on LED TV

So what are the possible cause for audio-video lag and flickering on HDMI output?

My thought is this might be problem of HDMI driver or Hardware composer in android

Comment: My first thought would be a signal problem. Try a different cable, and check that the connectors at both ends don't have bent/broken pins or fluff inside.

Comment: @DanHulme:Thanks for reply but cable is working fine with other android device

Comment: Definitely check the connector then. Sockets on dev boards are prone to collect fluff and/or come loose from the board.

Comment: Flickering is there when I set resolution of board to 1920x1080 other then this resolution there is no issue